# States of type III factors

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given any state of a type III$_1$ factor $\omega$ and any $\epsilon>0$ is there always a state of infinite multiplicity $\varphi$ such that $\|\omega-\varphi\|\leq \epsilon$?

A related question:
Given a projector $e$ in the algebra and a state $\varphi$, is there always a state near $\varphi$ that has $e$ in its centralizer?

Comment: What's the multiplicity of a state?

Comment: According to Takesaki's book Vol II pg 405 a semi-finite normal weight $\varphi$ has infinite multiplicity if its centralizer $\mathcal{M}_\varphi$ is properly infinite.